# Prove that $(2^{a}-1)=(2^{b}-1)l + (2^{r}-1)$ when $a=bk+r$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

My problem:

Prove that for all positive integers $a$ and $b$,  $2^{a}-1=(2^{b}-1)l + (2^{r}-1)$ if $a=bk+r$ and $0\leq r < b$, where $l$, $k$, and $r$ are also positive integers.

So far I have taken $(2^{bk+r}-1)=(2^{bk}*2^{r} - 1)$ but I can't seem to reach a result.

Any hints? I am a little lost. Thanks!

Comment: Write it as $(2^a - 2^r) + (2^r - 1)$.

Comment: Great thanks. Now I am stuck here: 
$2^{r}(2^{bk} - 1) + (2^{r} - 1)$. 

It is unclear to me how to pull $k$ out of $2^{bk}$.

Comment: You probably have seen the factorisation of $x^k - 1$. Take $x = 2^b$.

Comment: Oh that is so obvious now. I really appreciate the help!